# code called after window load not finding element

Tags: javascript, html, window

I have a little piece of code written in JS to change the theme of a page. There is a button that calls this code, and the JS code should create a border around the button when it is selected. However, even though I call this code after the page reload, Google Chrome's developer tools keeps saying, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null". It is referring to the line of code that adds the border.

Here is the button on the HTML page:

```
<div id="colBlack" title="Theme: Black" onclick="changeBackColor('Black')"></div>
<div id="colWhite" title="Theme: White" onclick="changeBackColor('White')"></div>
```

Here is some of the JS code (the PHP response will return either "Black" or "White" after processing some information):

```
window.onload = function() {
    // irrelevant lines of code
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","res/setTheme.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            changeBackColor(xmlhttp.responseText);
    // irrelevant lines of code
}
function changeBackColor(color) {
    if(color == "White") {
        opp = "Black";
        right = "48px";
    } else {
        opp = "White";
        right = "78px";
    }
    document.getElementById("col" + color).style.border = "2px solid " + opp;  // line of code Google Developing Tools refers to
    document.getElementById("col" + opp).style.border = "none";
    document.getElementById("col" + opp).style.top = "10px";
    document.getElementById("col" + color).style.top = "8px";
    document.getElementById("col" + color).style.right = right;
    document.getElementsByClassName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = color;
    var elemType = Array("p","span","h1","h2","h3","h4","h5","h6");
    for(var tE = 0; tE < 8; tE++) {
        for(var textElem = 0; textElem <     document.getElementsByTagName(elemType[tE]).length; textElem++) {
            if(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName(elemType[tE])[textElem],null).getPropertyValue("color") == "rgb(0, 0, 0)" || window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName(elemType[tE])[textElem],null).getPropertyValue("color") == "rgb(255, 255, 255)")
                document.getElementsByTagName(elemType[tE])[textElem].style.color = opp;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it because the `changeBackTheme` function is outside the `window.onload`, and it is being parsed before being called? If so, how do I stop it? If not, what is the problem?

If you need more code to figure this out, please tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: you can use jquery `$(document).ready` or call the `window.load` at the end of your page

Comment: @̇̇̇ what difference does the jquery code make from regular javascript? and would calling `window.load` at the end of the page make a difference? I'll try it but I don't understand why.

Comment: It is NOT because `changeBackColor()` is outside the `onload` function.  That makes no difference here.

Comment: Also, do you really want to be doing this: `document.getElementsByClassName("body")[0]`.  Do you have elements with a `class="body"`?  Or do you want the `<body>` tag which is just `document.body`?

Comment: @jfriend00 good point - i was just coding fast. thanks

Comment: If you really think the error is on this line `document.getElementById("col" + opp).style.border = "none";`, then add these debugging lines `console.log("col" + opp)` and `console.log(document.getElementById("col" + opp))` to see what is going on.

Comment: You might also want to read about [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).  Repeating the same `document.getElementById()` multiple times in a row is a poor practice.  Also want `var` on ALL local variables.

Comment: If the issue is on this line: `document.getElementById("col" + color).style.border = "2px solid " + opp;`, then probably `color` isn't what you think it is.  Add `console.log()` statements to see what that is.  This is basic debugging.  Learn to use the debugger to set a breakpoint and step though this code and you'd see your problem in 10 seconds.

Comment: @jfriend00 using `console.log()` shows: `colWhite` and `<div id="colWhite" title="Theme: White" onclick="changeBackColor('White')"></div>`, which it is supposed to show - I'll check the colors - wow, i never knew about `console.log()` until now. Thanks

Comment: When you discover the debugger, breakpoints, the watch list and stepping through your code a line at a time, you'll wonder how you ever solved any problem efficiently before.  Learning your tools will help you immensely.  You can read a bit [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Comment: So, what did you figure out?

Comment: @jfriend00 I was using JQuery and replacing all the long `document.getElementById()` statements, and I fixed the line where it says `document.getElementById("col" + color).style.right = right`, and it works now. sorry about all the trouble for my careless mistakes - I learned a few things though, so thanks